# What is the deeper meaning of yo mama jokes in the Talmud?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Talmud, in discussing the meaning of the word "אור," proposes astoundingly that:

> אלמא אור יממא הוא
>
> Thus we see that אור is yo mama
>
> - [Pesachim 2a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=2&format=pdf)

Indeed, it's only a hava ameina. But every hava ameina must be taken seriously.

Could anyone shed light on the deeper meaning of this statement?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

One possible explanation:

Yo mama is Kneset Yisrael. "שמע בני מוסר אביך ואל תטוש תורת אמך"

Our sages were praying that Israel be redeemed from its exile.

This explanation is backed up by a verse in [Psalm 42](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c2642.htm):

> ט יוֹמָ֤ם ׀ יְצַוֶּ֬ה יְהוָ֨ה ׀ חַסְדּ֗וֹ    וּ֭בַלַּיְלָה שִׁירֹ֣ה עִמִּ֑י 
>   תְּ֝פִלָּ֗ה    לְאֵ֣ל חַיָּֽי׃
>
> Yo mom, God will assign his kindness, and at night his dwelling is with me, a prayer to the God of my life.

What's more, the ta'am under the word יומם is the "big" variant of the shofar mehupach. A big shofar. What is the association?

> ובשופר גדול יתקע, וקול דממה דקה ישמע...

And this is what the next psalm ([43](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c2643.htm), which seems to be a continuation of Psalm 42) prays about when it says:

> שְׁלַח־אֽוֹרְךָ֣ וַֽ֭אֲמִתְּךָ    הֵ֣מָּה יַנְח֑וּנִי

אור - כדאמרן

And as for אמ"ת - perhaps it's needed in order to understand the previous proof.